# Show Cognitive Complexity of method in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, sonarlint, sonarlint-vs

While using SonarLint and SonarQube in Visual Studio (2017), is there a way to display the Cognitive Complexity of a method anywhere?

It is shown when it exceeds the maximum value, but I can't seem to find where I can see it once I'm below the threshold.

[image: "Refactor this method to reduce its Cognitive Complexity from 29 to the 15 allowed"]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Resharper in Visual Studio you can use the [cognitivecomplexity](https://github.com/matkoch/resharper-cognitivecomplexity) resharper plugin.

It shows the cognitive complexity even though it is below the (in Resharper options configurable) threshold

[image: Cognitive Complexity in tooltip]